# HTHangEventCreate fails?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Creating a Nativescript-vue app with nativescript-nfc plugin.  I have the following:

```
<script>
const applicationSettings = require("application-settings");

var Nfc = require("nativescript-nfc").Nfc;

export default {
  methods: {
    onButtonTap() {
      if (this.nfcEnabled) {
        this.nfc
          .setOnNdefDiscoveredListener(
            data => {
              if (data.message) {
                data.message.forEach(record => {
                  console.log("Scanner:NdefListener=" + record.payloadAsString);
                  this.nfcLastTagRead = record.payloadAsString;

                  if (this.nfcLastTagRead) {
                    let fob = fobService.findFob(this.this.nfcLastTagRead);
                    console.log(
                      "found "this.this.nfcLastTagRead);

                  } else {
                    console.log("nfcLastTagRead is falsy");
                  }
                });
              }
            },
            {
              stopAfterFirstRead: true

            }
          )
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Scanner:setStartNdefListener added");
          })
          .catch(err => console.err(err));
      } else {
        console.log("NFC is not enabled or available on this device");
      }
    },
    lookupId: function() {
      console.log("in the lookupId()");
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      nfc: null,
      nfcEnabled: false,
      nfcLastTagRead: ""
    };
  },

  beforeMount: function() {
    const uuid = applicationSettings.getString("deviceId");

    // instantiate the plugin
    this.nfc = new Nfc();

    this.nfc
      .available()
      .then(available => {
        console.log("Scanner:available=" + available);
        return this.nfc.enabled();
      })
      .then(enabled => {
        console.log("Scanner:enabled=" + enabled);
        this.nfcEnabled = true;
      })
      .catch(err => console.err(err));


  }
};
</script>
```

When I run this on startup and on button click() I get the following in my console :

> CONSOLE LOG file:///app/bundle.js:377:18:
>   \134^[[32m'Scanner:available=true'\134^[[39m CONSOLE LOG
>   file:///app/bundle.js:380:18:
>   \134^[[32m'Scanner:enabled=true'\134^[[39m HTHangEventCreate:
>   HangTracing is disabled. Not creating a new event.

I see that the NFC plugin actually works, but seems to stop after the message.  Been searching for this particular error message and all results point to a plugin issue with Firebase, but I am not using that nor having any of those dependencies in my project.

Comment: Is it platform specific, iOS / Android?

Comment: I am only testing on iOS, so cannot say for certain.

Comment: May I know what `fobService` actually does in your code, is the result same when you comment it?

Comment: it just looks up the value from a local list.  The message is given at startup and once the button click gets the scanned value and before reads it from the list